# Quality Assurance Engineer and Business Analyst

Tags: quality-assurance, career-development

I need your suggestions as I am working for the company as software quality assurance engineer and Business analyst so what would be my role all together?

Any special or alternative role for being specific? Or, should I use both for my further job hunt?

Answer (score 1):

Job title and position role are completely company dependent and often only remotely related. So it depends on company (and presumably country).

Also, quality cannot be assured (presumably by testing). Quality has to be build-in, and testing only can show if defect were detected. If tests are itself of low quality, it will falsely report no bugs (when we can only tell "no **detected** bugs".

I consider myself working in **quality assistance** area: providing management information on current status of the quality of our product.

Answer (score 1):

**I would say it's a deadly combination, a Business Analyst with good understanding of quality assurance**

You can use both for your further job hunt. Both these role complement each other. 
A business analyst with QA knowledge can better understand quality related challenges/benefits while proposing a business solution.

A quality analyst with strong business knowledge can bring in more value to his work (can identify more business test scenarios than other analysts which results in better quality and test ware and finally better quality).

So, anybody would love to hire a quality analyst who has also taken care of business related aspects. And also, anybody would love to hire a business analyst who is well versed with quality related aspects.

In my opinion, you should highlight both the aspects whenever you apply for a job. You can give more weight age to one of these depending upon your personal preference. I mean, if you enjoy quality related work more; then you can highlight it more than the BA related work but still you should mention both.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I want to ask whether should I apply as Qualty Analyst for my further job hunting?

Comment: Your decision largely depends on you. For example, if you ask me, I would apply as a quality analyst because of my interest in quality. Even if there is more money in BA profile, I would still choose QA. So, it depends on you. What are your priorities. But both the profiles are good and in demand. I would have discouraged you if any of these two would not have been in demand.